# Proving that $\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}<x-\ln(1+x)<\frac{x^2}{2}$, $x>0$. Using mean value theorem only

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Using applications of the MVT, prove that $\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}<x-\ln(1+x)<\frac{x^2}{2}$, $x>0$.

I am not able to choose the required function for the mean value theorem. I have to use only the differential form of the mean value theorem. I don't know how I am supposed to do this. Any help or any other method you could offer would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Check out [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you're asking a good question - most people on here want to see what work you've done and where you're getting stuck. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format any mathematical expressions to avoid ambiguity - for example, is the $2*(1+x)$ in your problem statement all in the denominator, or just the 2?

Answer (score 2):

Take $$f(x)=x-\ln(1+x)-x^2/2 \implies f'(x)=\frac{-x^2}{1+x}<0, ~if~x>0$$
So $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x>0$. Then $x>0 \implies f(x)<f(0)=0.$
This proves that $$x-\ln(1+x)<\frac{x^2}{2}$$
Next take $g(x)=x-\ln(1+x)-\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)} \implies g'(x)=\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)^2}>0.$
So $g(x)$ is increasing function, then $x>0 \implies g(x) >g(0)=0$, we prove that $$x-\ln(1+x)>\frac{x^2}{2(1+x)}.$$

Comment: I am supposed to use only Lagrange mean value theorem